# How to create a SharePoint list Template for a list for which threshold is breached?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view-threshold, list-template

I have a list whose threshold limit is breached (over 5000 items). How to create a list template for this list?

Comment: Have you tried making a template without the content?

Comment: did you tried below steps?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps and check if it works fine for you.

1 - Please export the list without data through  pnp powershell and create a new list to destination site.

Refer the below article

[Move list from one site to another site](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/move-sharepoint-listlibrary-from-one-site-to-another-with-data-or-without-data/)

2 - Export data to Microsoft access table and then Import in destianation SharePoint site.

Refere the below article

[Export and Import data to SharePoint through Microsoft Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-link-or-move-data-to-sharepoint-65bf7b03-74bf-445c-959a-24b7a401ddee#:%7E:text=Access%20opens%20the%20Get%20External,that%20you%20want%20to%20import.)